# argument of type 'TextChannel' is not iterable

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So I am trying to make an `on_message` event that when someone says something in a specific channel then the bot will react to that message with the like and dislike emojis but I keep getting the error in the title.

```
async def on_message(message):
  await client.process_commands(message)
  channel = client.get_channel(738118906475970640)
  if message.content in channel:
    await message.add_reaction("")
    await message.add_reaction("")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is, that u try to check if a string (message.content) is in a discord.TextChannel object (channel).

I think you are searching for something like

```
async def on_message(message):
    if message.channel.id == 738118906475970640:
       # react to these emojis
```